# Remap an Array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have below input and needs the output. Could you all give way to get the output

```
var input= [
  {
    "genre": "Genre 1",
    "movies": [
      {
        "name": "Movie 1",
        "rating": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Movie 2",
        "rating": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "genre": "Genre 2",
    "movies": [
      {
        "name": "Movie 3",
        "rating": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Movie 4",
        "rating": 5
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Expected Output looks like below

```
output=[
  {
    "rating": 3,
    "movies": [
      {
        "name": "Movie 3",
        "genre": "Genre 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "rating": 4,
    "movies": [
      {
        "name": "Movie 1",
        "genre": "Genre 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "rating": 5,
    "movies": [
      {
        "name": "Movie 2",
        "genre": "Genre 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Movie 4",
        "genre": "Genre 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The approach I took to solve:

```js
let newarr=[];
    for(let i=0;i<ip.length;i++){
        for(let j=0;j<ip[i].length;j++) {
          if(ip[i] != undefined && ip[i] != null) {
            newarr.push({
                "rating": ip[i].movies[j].rating,
                "movies": { "name": ip[i].movies[j].name, "genre":ip[i].genre}
            })
        }
    }
}
console.log(newarr);
```

Comment: please make an attempt and share it with your question

Comment: _..Expected Output looks like below.._ Where is your code that is trying to output as expected?

Comment: _"Could you all give easiest way to get the output"_ The easiest way is to hard code the output. The given code already works: https://jsfiddle.net/u5mgr8j3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const input = [
  {
    genre: "Genre 1",
    movies: [
      { name: "Movie 1", rating: 4 },
      { name: "Movie 2", rating: 5 },
    ],
  },
  {
    genre: "Genre 2",
    movies: [
      { name: "Movie 3", rating: 3 },
      { name: "Movie 4", rating: 5 },
    ],
  },
];

const tempResult = {};

input.forEach((curr) => {
  const { genre, movies } = curr;

  const collection = movies.map(({ name, rating }) => {
    if (tempResult[rating]) tempResult[rating].push({ name, genre });
    else tempResult[rating] = [{ name, genre }];
  });
});

const output = Object.entries(tempResult).map(([key, value]) => ({
  rating: key,
  movies: value,
}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks . Its a clear way and avoid multiple declarations.